# Webpack 2.0 migration of proress and modulesDirectores configuration directives

Tags: javascript, webpack

I need to migrate a webpack configuration to WebPack 2.0. Webpack is complaining about `progress` and `modulesDirectories` as:

```
progress: true,
  resolve: {
    modulesDirectories: [
      'src',
      'node_modules'
    ],
    extensions: ['', '.json', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
```

How to rewrite these configuration itens to support webpack 2.0 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`resolve.modulesDirectories` has been merged into [`resolve.modules`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-modules) (from the official [Migration Guide](https://webpack.js.org/guides/migrating/#resolve-root-resolve-fallback-resolve-modulesdirectories)). Simply rename it to `modules`:

```
resolve: {
  modules: [
    'src',
    'node_modules'
  ],
  extensions: ['', '.json', '.js', '.jsx']
},
```

The `progress` option does not exist anymore, instead you can use the `--progress` flag in the CLI:

```
webpack --progress [other options]
```

`webpack-dev-server` also supports it:

```
webpack-dev-server --progress [other options]
```